# Null Pointer exception while building gradle

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on my project and suddenly getting a null pointer exception at time of gradle build and my project is not able to open in latest android version due to null pointer exception.
Please help!!

Attaching screenshot with this

http://prntscr.com/dsjy37

Comment: try to clean and rebuild or uninstall studio and re-install it may work fine

Comment: don't Down someone's reputation's @Mukesh Mishra.
Mahonster answer is not wrong.
it is also reason of your Problem.i think you got it.
Try to Clean / Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time running `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Rebuild Project` fixes things like this.